# How to manage or increase JDBC max connection pool size?

Tags: corda

When there is a peak in traffic write/read to DB, there seems to been a congestion in the number of available connection pool ~10. This is causing some slow performance during high load where the some connection doesn't get released.

Is there a way to manage / configure the connection pool (i.e node.conf) ?

Comment: What's your use-case here?  Reading and writing to the database during what? In Corda 3.1, flows only need one connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the connection pool. The `dataSourceProperties` in the node configuration file (`node.conf`) can be set to anything `HikariPool` connection pooling supports, including `maximum pool size. See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP for further details.

Comment: would it look something like this "dataSource.maximumPoolSize" = X ?